# How to download CSV from masseyratings.com in R

Tags: r

Consider the URL  https://masseyratings.com/cb/ncaa-d1/ratings

If one clicks on "More" and chooses "Export" a CSV file of the ratings is downloaded.

How would I use rvest, httr, etc to directly download this file from R? (Ideally I would even skip the step of saving the file and just convert the cvs to a data frame right away, but I would be satisfied either way.)  I have tried to trace what is happening using the developer tools in chrome and firefox, but none of the examples with which I am familiar seem to apply to whatever is happening here.

Obviously it's not too difficult to just download the file and read it into R, but I would really like to automate the process.

The html code for the page include this:

```
<select class='mopulldown' id='pulldownlinks'>
  <option value=''>More
  <option value='cb/ncaa-d1/ratings?c=1'>Conferences
  <option value='/map.php?s=379387&t=11590'>Map
  <option value='/scores.php?s=cb2022&sub=11590'>Scores/Schedule Data
  <option value='/cb2021/ncaa-d1/ratings'>cb2021
  <option value='/team.php?t=11590&s=cb2022&all=1'>Rating Archive
  <option value='/scoredist?s=cb2022&sub=11590&x=s'>Score Distribution
  <option value='/extgms?s=cb2022&sub=11590'>Extreme Games
  <option value='/path?s=cb2022'>Transitive Path
  <option value='exportCSV'>Export
</select>
```

and it's the last selection that triggers the download of the CSV file.

Comment: Welcome to SO, CS Fuu! StackOverflow is not suited (nor intended) to be a tutorial site. There are several tutorials and vignettes for `rvest`, I suggest you start at its [website](https://rvest.tidyverse.org/) and see what you can come up with. In general, it is expected that you do your research and attempts *before* asking questions here, and when you do so, you include code you've tried (in a reproducible manner). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: I have used rvest, httr, etc for years to do web scraping and I have looked through numerous examples and tutorials.  But I just don't see how to click that button in R (there doesn't seem to be any obvious POST command that would do it).

Answer (score 0):

When I attempt to scrape something like that, I usually open up a web-browser devtools (often `F12`) and look at network traffic when I click the button; often it points to a `GET` or `POST` that returns the JSON data that will give me the data I want. Using the GET/POST url that created that JSON often precludes the need to do any HTML manipulation at all.

In this case, nothing happens when clicking `More` or `export`, instead it is already loaded in a clear URL.

```r
url <- "https://masseyratings.com/json/rate.php?argv=kiqB7tdov4KNhxOtPC9JHgV-OZNKvSJFAtoC3YxpTt4s72nWxxwgp35IAExoj-CvP3XmvNm8l6ksrUVUer342g..&task=json"
res <- httr::GET(url)
```

Confirm status 200:

```r
res
# Response [https://masseyratings.com/json/rate.php?argv=kiqB7tdov4KNhxOtPC9JHgV-OZNKvSJFAtoC3YxpTt4s72nWxxwgp35IAExoj-CvP3XmvNm8l6ksrUVUer342g..&task=json]
#   Date: 2022-03-11 15:08
#   Status: 200
#   Content-Type: application/json
#   Size: 86.3 kB
```

Look at the data:

```r
dat <- httr::content(res)
str(dat, max.level=1)
# List of 11
#  $ TI          :List of 5
#  $ CI          :List of 20
#  $ RI          : list()
#  $ DI          :List of 358
#  $ timestamp   : num 1.65e+12
#  $ rating      :List of 4
#  $ prevnextpage: int 0
#  $ seas        : chr "cb2022"
#  $ soid        : int 379387
#  $ suboid      : int 11590
#  $ subname     : chr " : NCAA D1"
```

From here, there is likely a lot that needs to be done to convert that to a `data.frame`. (FYI, the `export`ed data is imperfect, as it has missing column names and looks as if it does not contain all of the data within `dat`.)

Comment: Hmmm, I think what you're getting is the web page, which you would also get with the URL that I gave in the original question.  I know that I can clean this up to get what I want, but what I am hoping to do is bypass all that, since the csv that the manual download provides already gives me a clean version of what I want.  Maybe it's possible to provide further arguments to the URL that you use, but as you say, the network traffic from devtools shows nothing (I did check all that before I asked the original question).

Comment: I added some relevant bits from the page source to the original question.  And thanks for looking at this.

Comment: After looking at the output a bit more, I think I will go ahead and write a little code to manipulate the results into a data frame, which will be a pretty simple task.  I guess the question of how to trigger the web site to provide the csv directly will remain a mystery to me. Thanks again.

Comment: Nope, you're right, I thought the DI had the data that I need (CI has information about the columns), but it doesn't.  In fact, I have no idea what some of those numbers represent.  Maybe someone else will come along an suss out how to trigger the CVS download.

Comment: I  think that HTML-`form` is completely javascript-managed, which means you may be able to use `RSelenium` to get what you need ... though it's not 100% perfect/deterministic in its behavior (since it relies on load times, etc). Sorry, not much better to work with here, I dislike non-standard web-pages that try to use js-trickery to be "cool".